# Jhipster new Roles - Full authentication is required

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, roles

I have a problem where I cannot acces any url while logged in on an  accont with a custom defined ROLE.

To create the new roles for my app, I added my new roles in the `AuthoritiesConstants` class and in `authorities.csv`.
Then I manually inserted my new desired roles : `ROLE_STUDENT` and `ROLE_PROFESOR` in my h2-database.

Then I logged in on the admin account and tried and succeeded to create a new user with the `ROLE_STUDENT`.
Then I logged on to this new account and tried to access `http://localhost:9000/api/users` to get the full list of users.
I got the following error :

```
2020-03-19 10:59:05.687 DEBUG 13892 --- [ XNIO-1 task-15] base.aop.logging.LoggingAspect           : Enter: base.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2020-03-19T08:59:05.686Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2020-03-19 10:59:05.691 DEBUG 13892 --- [ XNIO-1 task-15] base.aop.logging.LoggingAspect           : Exit: base.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2020-03-19 10:59:05.693  WARN 13892 --- [ XNIO-1 task-15] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
2020-03-19 10:59:05.695  WARN 13892 --- [ XNIO-1 task-15] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource]
```

In my `SecurityConfiguration` class, this url falls under `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()`. So I was supposed to be able to access it from any account, as long as I am logged in.

To my dismay, it seems I cannot access any URL, apart from the home page, from this account. I manually checked my database to see if the user has been created and has the correct role. All is well there.
Can someone help me solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open the routes to the new roles too, this is done on the client side. This is more or less how it looks if you use angular.

The home component is open to anyone as you can see in the file `home.route.ts`.

```js
export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: [], // <- Empty, so anyone can access the home
    pageTitle: 'home.title'
  }
};
```

On the other hand, if you want to grant access to a new role in a regular component, you'll have to add it to the valid authorities array in your `[entity-name].route.ts`.

```js
export const fooRoute: Routes = [
  {
    ...
    data: {
      authorities: ['ROLE_STUDENT', 'ROLE_PROFESOR'],
      ...
    },
...
```

That gives access to any user who has either `ROLE_STUDENT` or `ROLE_PROFESOR`, but not regular users (who only have `ROLE_USER`). This was just an example.

In any case, if I understood your question correctly, you were trying to access an `api/...` mapping directly in your browser. That's not a good idea and it's good that it fails since the client usually adds stuff to most requests so that they are properly handled and validated by the server (`XSRF`, `auth token`, ...).

Comment: I was under the impression that the problem was a Spring security problem, not angular. Now I understand. Thank you for the answer and for your time !